# Go golang, syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting :

Tags: syntax, go

```
  func test(args ...string) {
    var msg map[string] interface{}

    i := 0
    msg["product"] = args[i++]
    msg["key"] = args[i++]
    msg["signature"] = args[i++]
    msg["string_to_sign"] = args[i++]
  }

  go build utils.go
```

after compile, I get the error message

```
    ./utils.go:28: syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting :
    ./utils.go:28: missing statement after label
    ./utils.go:29: syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting :
    ./utils.go:30: syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting :
    ./utils.go:31: syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting :
    ./utils.go:36: syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting :
    ./utils.go:37: syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting :
```

why can't I put i++ in index of slice? is there any limitation in index of slice?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> [Go Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://golang.org/doc/faq)
>
> [Why are ++ and -- statements and not expressions? And why postfix,
>   not prefix?](http://golang.org/doc/faq#inc_dec)
>
> Without pointer arithmetic, the convenience value of pre- and postfix
>   increment operators drops. By removing them from the expression
>   hierarchy altogether, expression syntax is simplified and the messy
>   issues around order of evaluation of ++ and -- (consider f(i++) and
>   p[i] = q[++i]) are eliminated as well. The simplification is
>   significant. As for postfix vs. prefix, either would work fine but the
>   postfix version is more traditional; insistence on prefix arose with
>   the STL, a library for a language whose name contains, ironically, a
>   postfix increment.
>
> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [IncDec statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#IncDec_statements)
>
> The "++" and "--" statements increment or decrement their operands by
>   the untyped constant 1. As with an assignment, the operand must be
>   addressable or a map index expression.
>
> ```
> IncDecStmt = Expression ( "++" | "--" ) .
> ```
>
> The following assignment statements are semantically equivalent:
>
> ```
> IncDec statement    Assignment
> x++                 x += 1
> x--                 x -= 1
> ```

Write,

```
func test(args ...string) {
    var msg map[string]interface{}
    i := 0
    msg["product"] = args[i]
    i++
    msg["key"] = args[i]
    i++
    msg["signature"] = args[i]
    i++
    msg["string_to_sign"] = args[i]
}
```

Which, in your particular case, simplifies to,

```
func test(args ...string) {
    var msg map[string]interface{}
    msg["product"] = args[0]
    msg["key"] = args[1]
    msg["signature"] = args[2]
    msg["string_to_sign"] = args[3]
}
```

Comment: 1. you can just use `i++` just fine, no need for `i += 1`. 2. for this specific code there's absolute no need to use "i". http://play.golang.org/p/6h1kMGl8xe

Comment: ++ adds no benefit if used like this :/

Comment: One of the best design decisions of golang.

Comment: @ShashankV you must be a Python lover and a C++ hater. :D

Comment: Even Google must be surprised how easily people will gobble up any decision when it's labelled as "a simplification"

Answer (score 20):

According to Language Specification, http://golang.org/ref/spec#IncDec_statements, i++ is a `IncDec statements`, which is a `statement`, but not a `expression`.As for `args[index]`,  index must be a `expression`. You want more details , just read it Go Language Specification, it's just what the language demand.

Answer (score 15):

As other people have said `i++` is  a statement in go, not an expression as it is in C. Go has a different way of expressing the same intent using multiple assignment:

```
func test(args ...string) {
    msg := make(map[string]string)
    i := 0

    msg["product"], i = args[i], i+1
    msg["key"], i = args[i], i+1
    msg["signature"], i = args[i], i+1
    msg["string_to_sign"], i = args[i], i+1

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", msg)
}
```

Your definition of `map` would have failed at runtime too.

Comment: Nicely put - didn't think to try it that way

Comment: `i = args[i]` is nothing else but confusing.

Answer (score 6):

`++` operator is disappointing. This is my hack:

```
func test(args ...string) {
    i := 0
    inc := func(i *int) int { *i++; return i }
    var msg map[string] interface{}

    msg["product"] = args[inc(&i)]
    msg["key"] = args[inc(&i)]
    msg["signature"] = args[inc(&i)]
    msg["string_to_sign"] = args[inc(&i)]
  }
```

Comment: You must return *i (int) instead of  i (*int) in inc function

Comment: Could you explain why it is disappointing?

Comment: @anldisr It is not possible to pass statements to functions. Languages, which distinguish between statements and expressions, are just disabled.