# Is there used incorrect terminology in description of a compile error as to 'for' syntax in golang?

Tags: go, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I tried to use something like

```
for i := 0; i < len(bytes); ++i {
        ...
}
```

It is not correct and I got an error

> syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting **expression**

It was because of `++i` is not an expression I thought.

Then I found out that `i++` (it works in `for` loop) is not an expression as well according to [the documentation](https://golang.org/doc/faq#inc_dec).

Also I met that in [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880663/golang-why-and-not-work-in-expressions) (now I think in all cases) a statement can not be used instead of expression.

Now if we come back to the error we see that `for` loop requires an **expression**. I was confused with that. I checked one more part of [the documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) it turns out `for` requires a statement.

> For statements with for clause
>
> A "for" statement with a ForClause is also controlled by its
>   condition, but additionally it may specify an init and a post
>   **statement**

I started with question (which I liked more than the final question because it was about language non-acquaintance as I thought)

Is it special case for loop syntax that statement are accepted as expression or are there other cases in golang?

During writing the question and checking the documentation I end up to a questions

Is there used incorrect terminology in description of the error that should be fixed not to confuse? Or is it normally in some cases to substitute such terms as statement and expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go golang, syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800242/go-golang-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting)

Comment: It doesn't answer why error says expression when statement is accepted as well, I don't think it's dupe

Comment: I actually wrote that ++i is not expression in my question so I didn't ask about it and pointed the same place in doc. I see that i++ is statement and I also wrote about it I don't see why error says expecting expression when I can use statement and it confuses.

Comment: Ah I see what you're asking now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming but about a not super helpful error message in a certain compiler.

Comment: I guess providing error messages is about programming

Comment: If you care about such stuff: Dig into the compiler, fix it and send a fix. Go is open source. SO is totally the wrong place for such discussions. Open a bug report or engage on golang-nuts.

Comment: If I was sure I'm right I could fix and created PR. But I'm not, that's why I asked. @Volker do you think I should ask about difference between usages terms statement and expression in bug report? :) Or should I probably use always specific forums instead of SO?

Comment: @DanielGrankin You're right, the error message is "somewhat" misleading, but it never bothered me. You get the same error message if you replace `++i` with `break` (or with any other non-simple statement). You may file an issue if you feel like it.

Comment: I'd like to say thank you guys who was interested in the question and tried to figure out the "issue". And also I'd like to say to everyone who reads the comment please don't close, discredit a question if you really don't know answer.

Comment: SO is not the place for linguistic discussions or nomenclature wars. Especially not in implementation dependent error messages. It does not matter whether the nomenclature is wrong or misleading, incorrect or generally accepted or correct. You are asking about a non-code, non-programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Primary expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#PrimaryExpr)
>
> Primary expressions are the operands for unary and binary expressions.
>
> ```
> PrimaryExpr =
>   Operand |
>   Conversion |
>   PrimaryExpr Selector |
>   PrimaryExpr Index |
>   PrimaryExpr Slice |
>   PrimaryExpr TypeAssertion |
>   PrimaryExpr Arguments .
>
> Selector       = "." identifier .
> Index          = "[" Expression "]" .
> Slice          = "[" [ Expression ] ":" [ Expression ] "]" |
>                  "[" [ Expression ] ":" Expression ":" Expression "]" .
> TypeAssertion  = "." "(" Type ")" .
> Arguments      = "(" [ ( ExpressionList | Type [ "," ExpressionList ] ) [ "..." ] [ "," ] ] ")" .
> ```
>
> Operators and punctuation
>
> The following character sequences represent operators:
>
> ```
> ++    
> --
> ```
>
> [Operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators)
>
> Operators combine operands into expressions.
>
> ```
> Expression = UnaryExpr | Expression binary_op Expression .
> UnaryExpr  = PrimaryExpr | unary_op UnaryExpr .
>
> binary_op  = "||" | "&&" | rel_op | add_op | mul_op .
> rel_op     = "==" | "!=" | "<" | "<=" | ">" | ">=" .
> add_op     = "+" | "-" | "|" | "^" .
> mul_op     = "*" | "/" | "%" | "<<" | ">>" | "&" | "&^" .
>
> unary_op   = "+" | "-" | "!" | "^" | "*" | "&" | "<-" .
> ```
>
> Operator precedence
>
> The ++ and -- operators form statements, not expressions.
>
> [IncDec statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#IncDec_statements)
>
> The "++" and "--" statements increment or decrement their operands by
>   the untyped constant 1. As with an assignment, the operand must be
>   addressable or a map index expression.
>
> ```
> IncDecStmt = Expression ( "++" | "--" ) .
> ```

---

`++` and `--` are operators. The `++` and `--` operators form statements, not expressions.

```
IncDecStmt = Expression ( "++" | "--" ) .
```

When the compiler encounters an `++` operator, it expects it to be immediately preceded by an expresssion.

For example,

```
package main

func main() {

    // syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting expression
    for i := 0; i < 1; ++i {}
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/y2d9ijeMdw

Output:

```
main.go:6:21: syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting expression
```

The compiler complains about the syntax. It found a `++` operator without an immediately preceding expression: `syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting expression`.

Comment: But we get the same error (`unexpected break, expecting expression`) even if we write `for i := 0; i < 1; break {}`. There is no expression expected before `break`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! The error is not very descriptive at least for me and now it is clear that description is reasonable and where it comes from.

Answer (score 3):

The Go Spec says the post statement of a for clause accepts (among other things) a [IndDec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#IncDecStmt) statement.

The IncDec statement is defined as: `IncDecStmt = Expression ( "++" | "--" ) .`

The parser finds an IndDec statement but an empty expression and thus spits out the error "expecting expression".

Edit: this probably fails because the fallback node to parse for a `SimplStmt` is an expression. The `IncDecStmt` failed, so it moves on to the default. The error accurately reflects the latest error that is bubbled up.

While the error message is correct, it is a little bit misleading. However, fixing it would involve passing more context about the current tree being parsed. eg: `bad ForClause: bad PostStmt: bad SimpleStmt: expected expression`.

There's still the problem that the `expected expression` is the last error encountered. Before that, it failed to parse the `IncDecStmt` but that error is swallowed because it falls back on an expression. The same applies at higher levels of the tree.

Even without that problem it would be rather heavy-handed and probably even more confusing than the current error messages. You may want to ask for input from the Go folks though.

Comment: so if someone tries to use statement instead of expression https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880663/golang-why-and-not-work-in-expressions he is downvoted and if error message says to use expresion when statement can be used as well it is normal, is's it?

Comment: I just want to know it's fine I'm not pretending it's not. For now I don't see it's normal.

Comment: This _could_ be the explanation, but since we get the same error message when we replace `++i` with `break` for example (or with any other statement that is not a simple statement), I don't think this reasoning is valid.

Comment: The SimpleStmt [parser](https://golang.org/src/cmd/compile/internal/syntax/parser.go) tries to match an expression if nothing else does. This means that if it doesn't fail on parsing others (eg: `SendStmt`, `Assignment`, etc...), it will fail trying to parse an expression.

Comment: As for `break`, the same thing happens. It's not allowed anywhere in the `SimpleStmt` so the last error bubbled up is the default parsing for an expression.

Comment: @Marc But regardless of the parser implementation the error message "expected simple statement" would be more appropriate.

Comment: I agree, and this goes back to my edit above about providing more context. This isn't straightforward though. A few things to think about: at what level of the grammar do you return an error? do you include all context? do you return all failed grammar nodes, or just the latest one?

Comment: @Marc The generated error message is for the _user of the tool_, not for the writer or maintainer of the tool, and therefore the error message should be the most _helpful and relevant to the user_, and not one that reflects _how_ or _when_ the parser drew the conclusion that the syntax is invalid.

Comment: I'm still in agreement. The issues I mentioned in my previous comments have to do with "exactly what error message do you return"? This is entirely about providing actionable information to the user without drowning them in a flood of irrelevant data. My only point is that there probably isn't a perfect answer when it comes to parsing, and certainly not an easy one.

Comment: @Marc Ok then (I missed the "agreeing" part).